# Is one of them wrong? "Working at a new job" vs. "Working in a new job"

Tags: prepositions

Can "at" and "in" be used interchangeably without worry or is one of them specifically wrong especially in the case of:

Working at a new job vs. Working in a new job?
and Living in a new apartment vs. Living at a new apartment?

Answer (score 1):

I'd reject "living at a new apartment", though "living at a new address" is idiomatically correct.

For a new job, it's less clear.